# shiny (Rstudio) package for R - no able to install on Mavericks

Tags: shiny, rstudio

I am about to begin a project with Shiny (by RStudio).  When I try to install the shiny package using the console `install.packages("shiny")`, I get the following error message:

```
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/shiny_0.10.1.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1/shiny_0.10.1.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
download of package ‘shiny’ failed
```

I have tried to install it from the drop down menu in RStudio but have encountered the same problem.  Any thoughts as to what is going on?

I am working on Mac, with the latest version of Mavericks (R version is 3.1.1).

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different `CRAN` mirror. The error indicates that the file was not found on the `CRAN` server

```
chooseCRANmirror()
```

`shiny` has just been updated `2014-10-01` so the changes may not have propagated down to all mirrors yet.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks -- much appreciated.